# What array name does Ember Data expect for sub directory models?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I recently started learning Ember and using Ember-CLI so I'm not quite well educated about Ember Data and what array names it expects for relationships that are in sub directories in my app.

```
// models/server.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  serverHistory: DS.hasMany("history/server", { async: true })
});

// models/history/server.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  server: DS.belongsTo("server", { async: true })
});
```

I've tried returning these names from my API

```
server_historys_ids
server_histories_ids
history_server_ids
history_servers_ids
```

But I don't see an XHR request for Server history in my application. The servers itself are fetched fine.

### Update

I changed my relationship name and the API is returning history ids but I'm still not getting an history json request even though I'm trying to `each` in the template. The game relationship data is accessible in the template and a request is successfully made.

```
// models/server.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  // attr's here.. not relevant

  // Relationships
  game: DS.belongsTo("game", { async: true }), // works
  serverHistories: DS.hasMany("history/server", { async: true }) // doesn't make a request like game does.
});
```

I also have an `adapter/history/server.js` but it's only telling what namespace to use - "api".

### Update 2

I think the problem may be in the way I'm calling the data to the model.

```
// routes/server/view/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var parentModel = this.modelFor("server.view");

    return this.store.query("server", { server_address: parentModel.server_address });
    // return this.store.find("server", 1);
  }
});
```

How come when I use find with an id it updates the template data and when I use query with parameters it doesn't?

### Update 3

So I got my `find` and `query` problem sorted out, here's the way I got it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31831667/1814027

The relationship problem still persists. I see no serverHistory data in my Ember toolbar nor a request being made to the API for it.

Comment: I would advise against putting models in subdirectories. The pain will not be worth it.

Comment: How could I improve my model and route then?

Comment: to @torazaburo: I am using namespaced models widely without feeling any pain. Moreover I feel comfortable with structured models.

Comment: Updated my question, see "Update 2".

Comment: When I return ¨server_history¨ from my api { "servers":.., "server_history":.. } Ember toolbar shows server history data is present. So my question is still the same: Why doesn't Ember load server history through a request if I'm returning only the server_history_ids? It gets the server_history data fine if I return them with servers request.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive `serverHistory` is anti-conventional name for `hasMany` and `serverHistories` should be instead.

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  serverHistories: DS.hasMany("history/server", { async: true })
});
```

Then in case of ActiveModelAdapter expected `server` payload is:

```
{"server": {"id": 1, "server_history_ids": [1,2,3]}}
```

It doesn't depend on the fact that `serverHistory` is namespaced model, it depends on relation name only.

For example for model:

```
// models/server.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany("history/server", { async: true })
});
```

expected payload is:

```
 {"server": {"id": 1, "bar_ids": [1,2,3]}}
```

**Update**
Working ember-cli example: https://github.com/artych/so_ember_data_subdir

Comment: I changed the hasMany name to serverHistories. Dev tools shows that server XHR request has been made (which includes server_history_ids) but no history request is being made. I'm using {{#each model.serverHistories}} in my template (even though this way is deprecated, it should work).

I don't see any history requests in the network tab nor history data in ember toolbar. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try to resolve `model.serverHistories` manually in afterModel (so you either see request or see errors).
// in server route
afterModel: function(server) {
    server.get('serverHistories').then(function(histories) {
        self.controllerFor('server').set('serverHistories', histories);
    }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
    });
}

Comment: Could I modify the code to work in setupController? I tried using your code but it didn't return any errors nor requests (I hade to modify controllerFor to ('server.view.index'))

Comment: it's strange... console.log(histories)? PS: `afterModel` is right place for resolving model-dependent promices.

Comment: May be the needed `serverHistories` are already fetched before? If so, they wouldn't be requested on server.get('serverHistories')

Comment: Emptying the cache + hard reload doesn't show any request being made. The serverHistories route doesn't exist in my API yet - shouldn't Ember throw some errors in that case if it already fetched it before and got an invalid response (html page)?

Comment: Kristjan, sorry, I am off for 12 hours, then I'll prepare simple working jsbin example for you.

Comment: I updated my question. I'm pretty sure my models are correctly done, but the way I'm requesting the data is probably incorrect.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Netifriik/91eaf5a2c7b6846e94f3 - I added every file that is related to the problem. Could you please check it out? I tried integrating your github example with my code but it still doesn't show histories.

Answer (score 0):

Artych's answer helped me on the right path but Ember didn't want to recognise `server_history_ids` so I just renamed the `hasMany` relation to `histories` and returned `histories: []` from my API. Now it works.. don't know why but it works.