# Ember store query template no model data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How come Ember model store `query` doesn't update template model data and `find` does?

```
// This doesn't update the template, when loading website no information is displayed but the data is loaded
model: function() {
    var parentModel = this.modelFor("server.view");
    return this.store.query("server", { server_address: parentModel.server_address });
}

// This works without any problems
model: function() {
    var parentModel = this.modelFor("server.view");
    return this.store.find("server", 1);
}
```

Comment: What version of EmberJS are you using? They should be exactly the same.

Comment: Ember version 1.13.3, Ember Data version 1.13.5

Comment: Edited my question, this is the problem im facing.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why my template was not rendering model data. Using `store.query` it expects multiple results while `store.find` expects only one result and that's why it worked. I was using `server_address` as an id in find but it started to get in my way.

Here's how I got `store.query` to work on a single result.

```
return this.store.query("server", { param: value }).then(function(res) {
    return res.get("firstObject");
});
```